# Replacing elements in 2D lists

Tags: python

My program is supposed to take the table  I created and replace all instances of this symbol: "-" and replace it with a number that corresponds with how many of this symbol "#" (The bomb) surround it.So far this is what I have:

```
import copy
# a function that takes a grid of # and -, where each hash (#) represents mine 
# and each dash (-) represents a mine-free spot
table=[
       ["-","-","-","#","#"],
       ["-","#","-","#","#"],
       ["-","-","#","-","-"],
       ["-","#","#","-","-"],
       ["-","-","-","-","-"]]
list2d= copy(table) #use copy to get the data from the list
for i in range(length(table)):
    for k in range(length(table[0])):
        if table[i][k]=='-':
            table_count=0  # set the loop to start counting at 0
            for a in(1, 2, 3):
                for b in(1,2,3):
                    if(0 <= i+a < length(table) and 0<= k+b <length(table[0]) 
                       and table[i+a]):
                        table_count += 1
    list2d[i][k]=str(table_count)

print(list2d)
```

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question, but I guess you're getting a problem because that's not a _deep_ copy.

Comment: This will throw an error as you import `copy` and then try to call it as if it is a function.

Comment: What is the `length` function? What do you expect the condition `and table[i+a]` to do?

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- `copy` is a module, not a function, so you cannot call it. But since you are asked to *replace*, and there is no mention of a new table, I don't see why you would need to copy the table.
- `length` is not a native function. It should be `len`.
- `and table[i+a]` is a strange condition. `table[i+a]` is a row in your table, and a non-empty one, so that is always a truthy condition. You should check that there is a `#` symbol in the *cell*, so `table[i+a][k+b] == "#"`.
- The indention for `list2d[i][k]=str(table_count)` is wrong. This should happen *within* the inner loop, and only when the cell has a hyphen.
- `(1,2,3)` are not the correct offsets to reach neighboring rows or columns. That should be `(-1,0,1)`.

Here is your code with those issues corrected:

```
table=[
       ["-","-","-","#","#"],
       ["-","#","-","#","#"],
       ["-","-","#","-","-"],
       ["-","#","#","-","-"],
       ["-","-","-","-","-"]]

for i in range(len(table)):
    for k in range(len(table[0])):
        if table[i][k]=='-':
            table_count=0
            for a in(-1, 0, 1):
                for b in(-1,0, 1):
                    if(0 <= i+a < len(table) and 0<= k+b <len(table[0]) 
                                             and table[i+a][k+b] == "#"):
                        table_count += 1
            table[i][k]=str(table_count)
```

If the input table should not be mutated, but a new table must be created, then create it why doing the counting. You can use list comprehension for all this:

```
result = [
    [
        "#" if cell == "#" else str(sum(
            0 <= i+a < len(table) and 0 <= k+b < len(row) 
                                  and table[i+a][k+b] == "#"
            for a in (-1, 0, 1) for b in (-1, 0, 1)
        )) 
        for k, cell in enumerate(row)
    ] for i, row in enumerate(table)
]
```